# Android Button layout in GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, intellij-idea, grid-layout

I have some problem. I want to make android layout resource file using GridLayout. I tried a lot but there is no result that I need. I want to make it using GridLayout.

Look at my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/how_we_perform_background"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="How are We performing?"/>
    <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="5">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_smile1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_smile2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_smile3"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_smile4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_smile5"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_row="1"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/under_smile_image"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/under_smile_image"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="2"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/under_smile_image"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="2"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/under_smile_image"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="2"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/under_smile_image"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_row="2"/>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here you can see that all of smiles are not in the phone display. What I make wrong?
Also I need that button don't scaling the images that I put into background.

[image: Wrong layout]

Answer (score 0):

Change your gridview to match_parent

```
 <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="5">
```

In reality, I would look at making the ImageViews a fixed size, so they all fit on the screen appropriately.